# Java extend class with a reflected class

Tags: java, reflection, extend

I tried to make a reflection to my code but I came across a problem because I had to extend class with reflected class, it was something like this:

I have this classes reflected:

```
"some.package.a.SomeClass"
"some.package.b.SomeClass"
```

and now I need to extend another class with one of them

```
public MyClass extends SomeClass {
    @Override
    public Object...
```

is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you give more details on what this is meant to achieve?

Comment: Reflection is something you do at runtime, extending classes is usually done at/before compile time. Are you using runtime byte code generation (cglib, byte buddy, ...)?

Comment: aw, if extending is done in compiling process then I cant do this, thanks for explaining...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233923/extending-class-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Using off-the-shelf Java, you cannot extend a class given to you only through reflection. There are third-party libraries that let you overcome this restriction ([see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4016305/335858)).

Extending a class requires defining a new class, and compiling it into bytecode. Reflection happens at run-time. It is inherently a read-only API, so you cannot emit new classes with it.

Implementing an interface gives you another option of using a [`Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), but you cannot specify your own base class.